# Multicols and multirows table

Tags: tables

i want to create this table structure:

```
+---+-------+
|   |  b    |
| a +---+---+
|   | c | d |
+---+---+---+
| e | f | g |
+---+---+---+
```

This is, what i have so far:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c |}{B} \\
    & C & D \\ \hline
    E & F & G \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

So there are some borders missing. I know I have to use `\cline`{-} command, but everytime I try `\cline{2-2}`, an error occures. Can somebody help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\cline` has to appear in a line without `\hline` command, perhaps that was your error?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\cline{2-3}` in this case to get that line below the 'B' 
cell.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c |} 
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c |}{B} \\
    \cline{2-3} 
    & C & D \\ \hline
    E & F & G \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]