# Using `\multirow`

Tags: tables, multirow

I need to build a table that looks like this:

[image]

Quite obviously the `\multirow` package must be what I'm looking for, but every example I've seen so far only shows how to do this the other way around - that is, we don't want to "divide" the first column, but the second or etc. Is there any way around this? What i am (stupidly) missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: A similar question, slightly different table to be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178680/multicols-and-multirows-table/178682#178682

Comment: Similar also to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178976/how-to-color-a-cell-of-a-table-using-multirow-and-center-the-cell-content

Comment: Will the table have any real content? If so, how should the alignment be in the right column?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, it will, and it should be left-aligned but on the middle (vertical-wise) of the cell. i'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @sylvia Well then have a look on my third example in the answer below. It should cover your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `booktabs` as vertical lines are distracting the reader. If you need them, just use my snippet below with `|l|l|` and normal `\hline` and `\cline{1-1}` commands.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % my recommendation. Used in first and second version
\usepackage{multirow} % just for the second and third version
\usepackage{caption} % optional for nicer vertical spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{table}%
 \caption{Your Table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
  top left&right\\
  \cmidrule(r){1-1}
  bottom left&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}%
 \caption{Your Table with Centered Right Side}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
  top left&\multirow{2}{*}{centered right}\\
  \cmidrule(r){1-1}
  bottom left&\\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}%
 \caption{Your Table with Vertical Lines}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  top left&\multirow{2}{*}{centered right}\\
  \cline{1-1}
  bottom left&\\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `(r)` is optional. Have a look, if you like it more without this constraint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A great online utility for creating LaTeX tables visually:
http://www.tablesgenerator.com/
gives:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
\toprule
 & \multirow{2}{*}{} &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(l){3-5} 
 &  &  &  &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please post complete answers and not just fragments of code

Comment: What do you think is missing?

Comment: `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}` ... `\end{document}` ;-)